# Why is Nullable<T> considered a struct and not a class?

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, type-constraints

I'm trying to define a generic class that takes any type that can be set to null:

```
public abstract class BundledValue_Classes<T> 
    where T : class
{
    private Tuple<T, object> _bundle= new Tuple<T, object>();
    public T Value
    { 
        get { return _bundle == null ? null : _bundle.Item1; }
        set { _bundle = new Tuple<T, object>(value, obj); }
    }
    //...
```

This works fine. I also want to create a derived class that can take any primitive type (int, double, etc), and simply resolve that into the same as the above class, but where the primitive is wrapped in a Nullable

```
public abstract class BundledValue_Structs<T> 
    : BundledValue_Classes<T?> 
    where T : struct
{
   //...
}
```

But for some reason, this doesn't work. I get the error: `The type 'T?' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'BundledValue_Classes<T>'`

Is it clear what I'm trying to do here? I don't want to have to copy paste the contents of the whole `BundledValue_Classes<T>` class just to handle the case of a primitive wrapped in a `Nullable<T>`.

Perhaps there's some way to set the type constraint on `BundledValue_Classes<T>` so that it will not only accept classes, but any type that can be assigned a null value (including `Nullable<T>` types, which appear to be the only exception to the rule.)

Comment: Side-note: I'd strongly advise you to follow .NET naming conventions. The name `customTuple<T>` doesn't do so...

Comment: @JonSkeet That was just me removing a lot of cruft from the class to make the example more clear.

Comment: It's fine to give clean, short examples - but you're not adding to the clarity by ignoring normal naming conventions.

Comment: Why is there a Java tag? Removing it..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Nullable<T>` *is* a struct, [as per the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It simply isn't a class. It's a value type, which looks a bit like this in terms of fields:

```
public struct Nullable<T>
{
    private readonly T value;
    private readonly bool hasValue;
}
```

The `null` value for a `Nullable<T>` type isn't a null reference, it's just a value where the `hasValue` field is false.

Note that `Nullable<T>` doesn't satisfy a condition for a constraint of `where TFoo : struct` however, as that's actually a *non-nullable* value type constraint. Basically `Nullable<T>` doesn't satisfy either the `class` or the `struct` constraint. There's no constraint which *does* only allow for nullable types (reference or `Nullable<T>`).

Comment: So `Nullable<T>` is magic beyond having special syntax? It's a type which is neither `: class` nor `: struct`?

Comment: @delnan: It's a type which satisfies neither of those type constraints, yes. It also has special boxing behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet - posted a followup question asking if there's a workaround to duplicating the class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597586/is-there-any-way-to-combine-these-almost-identical-classes-into-one

Comment: No workaround necessary. See my reply to your followup question. Nullable<T> is a struct, but nullable types i.e) `int?` or `double?`, are types that satisfy the <T> specifier.

Comment: @drankin2112: The OP wants to restrict the type parameter to nullable types. You simply can't do that. Saying "just don't use `Bundled<float>`" isn't a good answer, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, the type `Nullable<T>` is a struct which encapsulates a `T` and a flag which indicates whether it is valid.  Because the implementers of .NET didn't see any usefulness to being able to have a type which could encapsulate a thing of any thing and indicate whether it was valid, they decided that they didn't want to allow `Nullable<Nullable<T>>` [a decision I dislike, by the way], and rather than come up with a special constraint just for the generic parameter in `Nullable<T>`, they decided that even though `Nullable<T>` is a struct, it shouldn't satisfy a `struct` type constraint.

Personally, I'd have rather seen `Nullable<T>` either simply be an "ordinary" struct with exposed fields of type `bool` and unconstrained `T`, which could be used by e.g. `Dictionary.TryGetValue` to return a value and indicate whether it was valid (regardless of whether `TValue` was a class, a non-nullable struct, or a `Nullable<T>`), or else have it be a class containing a `T`.  The value of being able to say `someNullable != null` as a shortcut is minuscule compared to the confusion and complications it causes compared with `someNullable.HasValue`.  Still, .NET is what it is.  Personally, I would suggest generally avoiding nullable types, since one can't do much of anything with a nullable type without copying out the value first.  Such types also have some weird quirks with regard to thread safety (e.g. code that receives a `Nullable<T>` and observes that `HasValue` cannot safely assume that `GetValueOrDefault` will return `Default(T)`, even if nothing can possibly have modified the `Nullable<T>` since it was received).