# Is there any way to combine these almost identical classes into one?

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, type-constraints

Followup to this question: [Why is Nullable<T> considered a struct and not a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588711/why-is-nullablet-considered-a-struct-and-not-a-class)

I have two classes that essentially maintain a tuple of some user-supplied value with an internal object.

When the type of the user-supplied value is a primitive, I have to wrap it in a `Nullable<T>` so that it can take on a null value in the Tuple.

```
public class BundledClass<T> where T : class
{
    private Tuple<T, object> _bundle;
    public T Value
    { 
        get { return _bundle == null ? null : _bundle.Item1; }
        set { _bundle = new Tuple<T, object>(value, internalObj); }
    }
    //...

public class BundledPrimitive<T> where T : struct
{
    private Tuple<T?, object> _bundle;
    public T? Value
    { 
        get { return _bundle == null ? null : _bundle.Item1; }
        set { _bundle = new Tuple<T?, object>(value, internalObj); }
    }
    //...
```

I'd prefer it if I could do this with a single class that can take either primitives or classes as a type parameter, but I don't see any way around it. Not without coming up with some sort of custom `Nullable` class that can box any type (not just types `where T:struct`) so as to ensure that `Value` can always be assigned null;

It seems like I should at least be able to define the latter class as

```
public class BundledPrimitive<T> : BundledClass<T?> { }
```

But even that fails since `Nullable<T>` does not meet the `: class` constraint (as per the linked question).

Comment: If I'm a user of this class, how do I distinguish between the `Value` not being set and me having set the `Value` to null somewhere else in my program?

Comment: @mikez If the value has never been set, then the internal `_bundle = null`. If `Value` were set to null, the internal `_bundle` would be a `Tuple<T, object>(null, internalObj)`. Not that it matters, but the user can see this using a public get-only property that returns `_bundle`.

Comment: Yes that would be the difference in the internal state, but as a caller I don't have access to `_bundle`.

Comment: @Alain BTW, I chose the name `BundledStruct` instead of `BundledPrimitive` in my answer because the two are not quite the same. A `DateTime` is a struct but not a primitive, and `string` is a primitive in C# (though `Type.IsPrimitive` will return false), but it's not a struct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you simply designed your class like this:

```
public abstract class Bundled<T>
{
    private Tuple<T, object> _bundle;
    public T Value
    { 
        get { return _bundle == null ? default(T) : _bundle.Item1; }
        set { _bundle = new Tuple<T, object>(value, internalObj); }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it with a struct by specifying the type parameter as a `Nullable<T>`, for example:

```
Bundled<string> foo; // handles classes
Bundled<float?> bar; // handles structs
```

The only problem here is that it's possible that a user could use this class with a non-nullable struct—e.g. `Bundled<int>`. If that's really a concern in your application, you could declare more specific sub-types like this:

```
public class BundledClass<T> : Bundled<T> where T : class { }
public class BundledStruct<T> : Bundled<T?> where T : struct { }
```

You also can make the constructor for `Bundled<T>` internal so it can't be called from outside your assembly. This will ensure that the user doesn't create a custom sub-type to bypass your `BundledClass` / `BundledStruct` wrappers.

Comment: Can't use `default(T)`. If the user creates a `Bundled<double> foo`, I absolutely have to distinguish between when they've set `foo.Value = 0` vs when `foo.Value` is unset (and thus `_bundle = Tuple<T?, object>(null, internalObj)`).

Comment: I suppose that would work as well as the answer below, so long as no one ever tries to implement `Bundled<T>` without a type constraint.

Comment: @Alain As I said, you could make the constructor internal, so it can only be called from within your assembly. This means any external types that derive from `Bundled` won't compile (at least not without a fair amount of reflection). Make sure that `BundledClass` / `BundledStruct` provide public constructors if you want the user to be able to inherit from them.

Comment: This can be combined with a run-time check in a static constructor to ensure that `T` is "good". This is because there is no compile-time generic constraint. The static constructor should go `static Bundled() { if (typeof(T).IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("T must allow null."); }`

Comment: You can combine this approach with @Alain's and make `Bundled<>` abstract without adding any virtual methods to it. This won't stop code in same assembly from deriving from it, but it won't be usable as-is in the same assembly and with an internal ctor it will be off-limits for any other assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

Best I could come up with just now. It's still two classes, but it saves me from hundreds of lines of code duplication:

```
public abstract class Bundled<T>
{
    protected Tuple<T, object> _bundle;
    public abstract T Value { get; set; }

    //... Everything else
}

public class BundledClass<T> : Bundled<T> where T : class
{
    public sealed override T Value
    { 
        get { return _bundle == null ? null : _bundle.Item1; }
        set { _bundle = new Tuple<T, object>(value, internalObj); }
    }
}

public class BundledPrimitive<T> : Bundled<T?> where T : struct
{        
    public sealed override T? Value
    { 
        get { return _bundle == null ? null : _bundle.Item1; }
        set { _bundle = new Tuple<T?, object>(value, internalObj); }
    }
}
```